# How can I use code snippets in F#

Tags: f#

In C#, I can leverage code snippets as shortcuts to produce plumbing code quickly. Is this supported in F#?

For example, if I want to implement property getters and setters, can I do this? In C#, I could just type:

<kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

What options are available in F#?

Comment: F# is such an expressive language that you don't need 'plumbing code', so you don't need snippets either. This isn't entirely jokingly meant. While I don't think you can have code snippets in F#, I must also say that I don't miss that feature. OTOH, if you don't already use [Visual F# Power Tools](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools), you should strongly consider doing so.

Comment: @MarkSeemann ... I never even noticed (I just had to look because I really was under the assumption that you could have snippets for anything in VS ... well turns out you can't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature may be added as [VS extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d19080ad-d44c-46ae-b65c-55cede5f708b).

Comment: This is awesome. I'm writing a blog post now on it.